# CSS checkbox styling won't work

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I read a ton of topics on this subject, but in won't work for me...

I'm making a theme for wp atm but I'm stuck on CSS checkbox styling, This is my CSS:

```
 input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
    background-image: url('images/main-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 -311px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
       display:inline-block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   }

   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
    {
            background-image: url('images/main-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 -357px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
        width: 16px;
        display:inline-block;

        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
.lcheckbox {
        position: relative;
    top: 43px;
    right: 200px;
}
```

And ofcourse my HTML:

```
<input class='lcheckbox' type="checkbox" /><label for="checkbox">Remember me</label>
```

So, is there anybody who can help me?

Thanks

Okay, I've got the first thing fixed, but now wheb I click nothing happens, and the label text is like:
`Remember *Here's a enter, so we continue on the next line*
Me`

Comment: where's the `label` in your HTML? also it would be helpful if you describe what the issue is and if you provide a reproducible example in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you have `input + checkbox`. Isn't that improper HTML? Labels are supposed to surround checkboxes, especially since if they don't won't it not manipulate the checkbox if you click on the label text?

Comment: @Leeish Could u make that more simple for me? I'm Dutch, so my English is not that good.

Comment: and also it should be `input[type='checkbox']`

Comment: a label should surround a checkbox, not come after it I think.`<label><input type="checkbox"></label>`

Comment: @Mr Lister, isn't the `'` or `"` around checkbox required in the css?

Comment: @MrLister yeah you right, my bad ;) "This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text."

Comment: @Leeish only if the value contains spaces or other non-word characters.

Comment: @user3135286 Re your edit: The label text gets put in two lines, because the label is not wide enough to hold the whole line. It's only 20 pixels across! So only the left part is clickable, the part where the sprite is. You do see the sprite, don't you? Otherwise, check if main-sprint.pg exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<label for="checkbox">` works on an input that has the id `checkbox`.
Since your input doesn't have an id, it won't work.

Solution: give the input an id.

```
<input class='lcheckbox' type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(or any other id, as long as it matches the label's `for` attribute.)